# C# SixLabors.ImageSharp Image.Load<Rgba32> from Azure Blob URL

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage, sixlabors.imagesharp

- I have written some code that uploads images to Azure Blob Storage in the cloud.
- I then want to load the image from a cloud URL, using SixLabors.ImageSharp, and resize the image.

How do I get the below code to read from a cloud URL, as opposed to a local file path (stored on a hard drive)?

```
string imageFilePathUrl = GetImageFilePathUrlFromAzureBlob();
using (Image<Rgba32> image = Image.Load<Rgba32>(imageFilePathUrl))
{
    //Resize the loaded image URL...
}
```

Comment: is the image publicly available? if not, a straightforward URL wont cut it

Comment: @Ctznkane525 Yes, I've hardcoded a public image URL, for testing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an `Image.Load` overload that takes a URL string (https://docs.sixlabors.com/api/ImageSharp/SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.html#SixLabors_ImageSharp_Image_Load_System_String_). It will interpret the string as a file path, which it isn't.

You must download the image first, as it's not stored locally. You can use some Azure's storage client, or just download it with a HttpRequest. The easiest way would be with Flurl (https://flurl.dev/):

```
using Flurl;
using Flurl.Http;

string imageFilePathUrl = GetImageFilePathUrlFromAzureBlob();
Stream stream = await imageFilePathUrl.GetStreamAsync();
using (Image<Rgba32> image = Image.Load<Rgba32>(stream))
{
    //Resize the loaded image URL...
}
```